# Rocket league compatible with non xbox controller

Tags: pc, controllers, rocket-league

I'm looking to buy rocket league and an actek gamepad controller, a friend told me that i might need an emulator to get this gamepad to work with the game, is this true? i won't want to waste money on a controller that might or might not work at all.

Comment: For console or PC?

Comment: PC, i should have wrote that

Comment: B, would you happen to have a link to the gamepad in question?  I seem to find PS2/3-like controllers if I seach for "Actek Gamepad" but they look so different that it's possible there's a model number as well.

Comment: Rocket League is one of the few games that supports PS4 controllers out-of-the-box.  I'd be very surprised if they didn't support generic xinput controllers as well, since that is _much_ more common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on Rocket League's current support for generic controllers(it didn't support them in the past), but several games will require you to use a program to have the controller appear as a non generic, supported controller. I'm not sure what the cost of the Acteck controller is, but wired 360 controllers aren't all that expensive(you might even be able to buy one second hand), and will, to my knowledge, work for any Steam game that supports controllers if you're just looking to plug and play.